# Popupwindow with layout shadow

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm looking for PopupWindow with layout shadow, but I cannot see it. I want to do my PopupWindow with a little dim such as bottom sheet or dialog.

[image]

Comment: try using dialog fragment

Comment: message section is your popup?

Comment: @Vivekm i would like that my action bar is not dimmed, so dialog is useless there